# JavaScript code execution sequence, how does statements/code outside the EventListener works?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to JavaScript and chrome debugging tools. And, I have a hard time debugging the below code. I inserted the breakpoint to see how does "keys" get the latest key clicked or in other words, when does it get called I never see the controller/pointer stopping on `const keys=document.querySelectorAll('.key');` line of the code. So, if controller/pointer does not stop/reach to this statement during the code execution how does it pick the correct key from the DOM every time?
Also, the same thing happens with `keys.forEach(`, means the breakpoint does not work so if the controller/pointer is not stopping at this line then, how the removeTransition callback function gets called?

```
<div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>


<script>
function removeTransition(e)
    {
      if(e.propertyName!=='transform') return; // skip if this is not a transform
      this.classList.remove('playing');
    }
    const keys=document.querySelectorAll('.key');
    keys.forEach(
       key => key.addEventListener('transitionend',removeTransition)
    );
</script>
```

The complete code here https://jsfiddle.net/speckyfoxabhishek/6kdye3pr/3/

NOTE: in the above link, the sound files (.wav) are missing, but that should not matter as the question is related to the execution sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put a

```
window.onload = function () { }
```

To be sure your content is loaded before searching for DOM elements. Like this.

```
window.onload = function () { 
 const keys=document.querySelectorAll('.key');
    keys.forEach(
       key => key.addEventListener('transitionend',removeTransition)
    );
}
```

To answer your question, than it is possible to script tags be executed before content is loaded. This is a good example https://addyosmani.com/blog/script-priorities/

Comment: The content is loaded, the code is working perfectly fine, the problem is with my limited knowledge, I guess.

Comment: Also, the place where the script is kept is perfect for this execution. But I want to understand the flow control within the Javascript.